# cakephp 3.x ajax pagination

Tags: ajax, cakephp, pagination

How to implement ajax pagination in cakephp 3.x in a more cakephp way.

In **cakephp 2.x**, I have used below code to implement ajax pagination(JS Helper).

```
$this->Paginator->options(array('update' => '#content', 'evalScripts' => true));
```

and

```
$this->Js->writeBuffer();
```

Pl someone help me.

Comment: Here is a live example with code: http://sandbox.dereuromark.de/sandbox/ajax-examples

Answer (score 1):

I have done ajax pagination using below script. Add this script at the end of your ctp file.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".pagination a").bind("click", function (event) {
    if(!$(this).attr('href'))
        return false;
    $.ajax({
        dataType:"html", 
        evalScripts:true,
        success:function (data, textStatus) {$("#content").html(data);}, 
        url:$(this).attr('href')});
        return false;
    });
```

});